# Save one frame per second of video coming to Raspberry Pi via TV HAT

Tags: video, raspberry-pi

I need to record TV (DVB-T) using - Raspberry Pi 3 - [TV HAT](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-tv-hat/) -Python 3

I only need the FIRST FRAME PER SECOND, saved as a jpg file. Meaning, I will have 60 jpg files per minute.

any tool to do this on a Rpi 3 B+ running Raspbian?

Comment: On what OS should the software run? What is your price margin?

Comment: Rpi 3 B+, on Raspbian.

what do you mean by "what is your price margin?"

Comment: if it comes to paid software, how much would you be willing to spend. If it should be free as in "free beer", you can add the [tag:gratis] tag – for free as in "free speech", there's the [tag:open-source] tag.

Comment: thanks izzy. right now I am just doing experiments hour my use. no margin factor.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) by specifying the TV HAT as an input stream *but it may be worth looking at [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html) as a wrapper for this*.

FFMPEG can extract 1 frame per second or each keyframe as described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) and can take a stream as an input so all you need to do is find out the syntax for specifying that. Note that the order of arguments can be critical on FFMPEG.